# How can I excluding inputs with a class using .serialize()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery to serialize a form, but I would like to exclude all inputs with the class  .has-dynamic-prices .

I am using the following code below but it doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks!!

```
   var serialized_form =  $("#base-menu-form:input:not(.has-dynamic-prices)").serialize()
```

Comment: Presuming `base-menu-form` is the ID of your form, you need a space before `:input`.

Comment: @lonesomeday - that is correct. Well spotted. Marking to close as "typo-type"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering - `#base-menu-form` is the form ID

Try:

```
var serialized_form =  $('#base-menu-form input:not(.has-dynamic-prices)').serialize();
```

or

```
var serialized_form =  $('#base-menu-form input').not('.has-dynamic-prices').serialize();
```

Comment: @mplungjan If the ID is for the Form then it will work.

Comment: @mplungjan glad I could be some help, but your method was also good, no need to remove it :)

Comment: Ok, I undeleted it. It is an interesting alternative

Comment: Thank you WeBBer!! It worked!!

Answer (score 1):

[The other answer from weBBer works well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49324983/295783)

```
$("form input").not('.has-dynamic-prices').serialize()
```

Alternatively disable the fields before serialising

```js
$("form .has-dynamic-prices").prop("disabled",true); // works
console.log($("form").serialize())
```

```css
.hidden { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="f1" value="1"/>
<input type="text" name="f2" value="2" class="has-dynamic-prices" />
<input class="hidden"  name="f3" value="3"/>
<input type="text" disabled name="f4" value="4" /><br />
<textarea name="f5" class="has-dynamic-prices" rows="5" >Also ignore me although I am not an <input></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Nice alternative way, I will keep in mind this way.You have my support :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all elements for the form, you can use the plain Javascript [elements](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_form_elements.asp) property of the form, and then filter inputs based on that.

```
$($("myForm")[0].elements).not(".has-dynamic-prices").serialize()
```

Comment: @mplungjan no, per the spec, the elements property accounts for all of those.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am saying. If you only have input, then `$("form input").not('.has-dynamic-prices').serialize()` will work faster